# R Programming; Calculate median of row using FOR loop

Tags: r, median

How would I calculate the median (use the median function) of each row by using the FOR loop.

Using a matrix;
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 5)

Thank you in advance.

-Bill

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution:

```
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 5)

medians_of_mat <- numeric()
for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  medians_of_mat[i] <- median(mat[i, ])
}
```

An easier way would be to use apply:

```
apply(mat, 1, median)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowMedians` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMedians(mat)
```