# Compute median per column in loop

Tags: r, loops, median

I have this loop to compute the mean per column, which works.

```
for (i in 1:length(DF1)) {     
    tempA <- DF1[i]                                 # save column of DF1 onto temp variable 
    names(tempA) <- 'word'                          # label temp variable for inner_join function
    DF2 <- inner_join(tempA, DF0, by='word')        # match words with numeric value from look-up DF0
    tempB <- as.data.frame(t(colMeans(DF2[-1])))    # compute mean of column
    DF3<- rbind(tempB, DF3)                         # save results togther
}
```

The script uses the dplyr package for `inner_join`.

- DF0 is the look-up database with 3 columns (*word, value1, value2, value3*).
- DF 1 is the text data with one word per cell.
- DF3 is the output.

Now I want to compute the median instead of the mean. It seemed easy enough with the [colMedians function from 'robustbase](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robustbase/versions/0.93-0/topics/colMedians)', but I can't get the below to work.

```
library(robustbase)

for (i in 1:length(DF1)) {     
    tempA <- DF1[i]
    names(tempA) <- 'word'
    DF2 <- inner_join(tempA, DF0, by='word')
    tempB <- as.data.frame(t(colMedians(DF2[-1])))
    DF3<- rbind(tempB, DF3) 
}
```

The error message reads:

> Error in colMedians(tog[-1]) : Argument 'x' must be a matrix.

I've tried to format DF2 as a matrix prior to the colMedians function, but still get the error message:

> Error in colMedians(tog[-1]) : Argument 'x' must be a matrix.

I don't understand what is going on here. Thanks for the help!

Happy to provide sample data and error traceback, but trying to keep it as crisp and simple as possible.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried to use the median function from the stats package?

Comment: Try `colMedians(data.matrix(DF2[-1]))`.

Comment: Change colMedians for apply: tempB <- as.data.frame(apply(DF2[-1], 2, median))

Comment: Why `*_all*` approach wouldn't work here as in: `mtcars %>% summarise_all(funs(median))`? I reckon that some sample data would help.

Comment: @MrFlick anticipating this comment I said I'd provide data if required :-) guess that is redundant now.

Comment: @RuiBarradas in the nerd spirit had to try your solution as well. worked perfectly. Want to post it so I can accept it as answer?

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz the apply family did help. However, I don't need to get rid of the first row, instead need to specify the columns as the joined DF2 inherits the data structure from the look-up DF0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment by the OP, the following solved the problem.
I have added a call to `library(dplyr)`.
My contribution was `colMedians(data.matrix(DF2[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)`.

```
library(robustbase)
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:length(DF1)) {     
    tempA <- DF1[i]
    names(tempA) <- 'word'
    DF2 <- inner_join(tempA, DF0, by='word')
    tempB <- colMedians(data.matrix(DF2[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
    DF3 <- rbind(tempB, DF3) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955409/r-programming-calculate-median-of-row-using-for-loop) which helped me fix the loop as following:

```
DF3Mean <- data.frame()                         # instantiate dataframe 
DF4Median <- data.frame(                        # instantiate dataframe

for (i in 1:length(DF1)) {     
tempA <- DF1[i]                                 # save column of DF1 onto temp variable 
names(tempA) <- 'word'                          # label temp variable for inner_join function
DF2 <- inner_join(tempA, DF0, by='word')        # match words with numeric value from look-up DF0
tempMean <- as.data.frame(t(colMeans(DF2[-1]))) # compute mean of column
DF3Mean <- rbind(tempMean, DF3Mean)             # save results togther
tempMedian <- apply(DF2[ ,2:4], 2, median)      #compute mean for columns 2,3, and 4 
DF4Median <- rbind(tempMedian, DF4Median)       # save results togther
}
```

I guess I was too stuck in my mind on the colMedian function.